# If there is less than a 100% chance that X might occur, can it occur?

Tags: modal-logic

The key word is **might**. If there is a 100% chance that a thing **might** occur, that does not mean there is a 100% chance it **will** occur! It **might** not occur, even though there is a 100% chance it **might** occur. Even though there is a 100% chance, since we are evaluating a situation in which even with a 100% chance it **might** occur, it still **might not** occur, because **might** represents a possibility. If the possibility is not assured, then it's not possible.

If there is a 100% chance that a thing **could possibly** happen, that means it **might not** happen. Now, let's just add that if it is not assured that a thing **could possibly** happen, then it can't possibly happen.

The difficulty with the concept is that might and possibly--used interchangeably--must cover every probability, because in essence that is what they mean. You cannot rationally state that a thing might happen unless there's a 65% chance of it happening. Might and possibly imply all probabilities. If one or more probabilities is removed, it becomes less than assured a thing could possibly happen. If it's less than assured that a thing could possibly occur, then it can't possibly occur. There's only two choices or they fail.
There must be a 100% chance that something might occur for it to have any chance of occurring.

If there's less than a 100% chance, then might is no longer might, but only a chance of might, which is itself only a possibility of a possibility. If possibility is not assured, it fails to be a possibility.

Ok, so we have a collection of individuals who simply lack the intellect to understand the concept. That's understandable. My intellect is 4 standard deviations from the mean. But if you silence what you can't understand, you prove there are obvious limits to human intellect, but none whatsoever on stupidity.

Comment: Read the question carefully.

Comment: Oh sorry I misread "if there iess than". Any event with a chance greater than 0% can happen, but only 100% means it *will* happen. TBH I'm baffled by this question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The question cannot be made more clear. No other information is required. It would simply confuse the issue. It requires critical thinking. Think about what the question means.

Comment: Yes, it has a 7 out of 10 chance of happening. It can happen, but it might never happen. No one will ever find truth by excluding common sense and self-evident truth from their resources!

Comment: Wow, down votes because no one can figure out the answer.

Comment: There's no chance that this question will not be closed.

Comment: It’s difficult to see how this question is useful to users at Philosophy.SE - if there’s a 70% chance it will rain tonight, then logically, it is then possible it will rain tonight. We need a context to understand why this is being asked (that is, why the intuitive answer might be faulty).

Comment: If what you have in mind is an iteratively modal sentence, e.g. it is possible that it is possible that A, then the wording could be clearer. In general, it is not guaranteed that if A is possibly possible then A is possible, but in many cases this is the case. If the modality is handled using probabilities, then we can use the chain rule. There is no general requirement that the outer probability must be 1 in order for the iterated probability to have a non-zero value...

Comment: If there is a 0.5 probability that Fred chooses to eat the stew and a 0.7 probability that if he does he gets food poisoning, then there is 0.7 probability Fred might get food poisoning. If the only other option is the salad and Fred cannot get food poisoning from that, then the probability of Fred getting food poisoning is 0.35.

Answer (score 2):

The probability of something happening when added to the probability of it *not* happening always comes out to be *one*.

Probabilities tell you what the *odds* are for a certain outcome in a trial which means they only make sense in the context of many, many trials. Probabilities cannot be used to predict the exact outcome of any trial; a 40% probability of a specific outcome only means that out of ten trials, 4 of them will come out that way- *on average*.